# overlap score matrix biopython

Tags: python, string-comparison, overlap, biopython

I have a FASTA file with DNA sequences and the names of the sequences and I need to make a matrix of the overlap scores. I found the module `pairwise2` in Biopython which seems to do this quite well. Except my sequences are already aligned and when I use `pairwise2` it again tries to align the sequences which takes very long and obviously gets the same overlap scores for every alignment. So my question is how do I get the overlap score without it trying to align the sequences again?
Here is what I have so far:

```
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import pairwise2

fasta_file = SeqIO.parse('unambiguous.fasta', 'fasta', alphabet=IUPAC.ambiguous_dna)

all_seq = []
for seq_record in fasta_file:
    all_seq += [str(seq_record.seq)]

compare = pairwise2.align.globalms(all_seq[0], all_seq[1], 2, -1, -1, 0)
print(compare)
```

I've used only the first and second sequence from the FASTA file here as a tryout. As you can see in the script matches should rewarded 2 point, mismatches and gaps -1. The 0 should be the reward when both sequences have a gap on the same position. I know that putting the 0 in the 4th position will not give me the desired result but I don't have a solution for that problem yet. The alignment problem seems bigger at this point.
So anybody with some experience with pairwise2 or other python/biopython modules that can get me the overlap scores?

Comment: Do you mean that `unambiguous.fasta` contains aligned sequences?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include example input that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, `unambiguous.fasta` contains aligned genetic sequences. You can score them using a scoring function that suits your needs:

```
from itertools import starmap, combinations


def score(seq1, seq2):
    def score_(a, b):
        return (0 if a == b == "-" # both are gaps
                else -1 if a != b  # mismatch or gap
                else 2)            # match

    return sum(starmap(score_, zip(seq1, seq2)))
```

You might want to modify it to ignore positions with ambiguous bases, as people usually do. Here is a neat way to compare all sequences:

```
sequences = SeqIO.parse('unambiguous.fasta', 'fasta', alphabet=IUPAC.ambiguous_dna)
scores = starmap(score, combinations(sequences, 2))
```

Once executed, `scores` (note that it is a lazy iterator) will generate the flattened upper triangle of the pair-wise matrix of scores. `score` should work pretty fast, though you might want to reimplement in using Cython or Numba, in case there are thousands of sequences (i.e. millions of comparisons to calculate).

*Edit* On Python 2.x you might want to replace `zip` with `izip`.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to do the trick in a simple and understandable way. It just doesn't wan't to print out the scores, because I get:
    <itertools.starmap object at 0x08B637F0>
Any idea about what it might mean?

Comment: @JDh You're welcome. In the answer I wrote: "note that it is a lazy iterator". You can either iterate over it and do something with the scores one by one (you would do that if you didn't want to load all scores into RAM at once) or transform it into a non-lazy container, e.g. `list(scores)`. Python makes heavy use of lazy evaluation. If you want to use the language efficiently, you should make yourself comfortable with the concept.